# procedure cursor return variables and loop over query

Tags: oracle, loops, plsql, cursor, procedure

I have a question about this procedure.  What I am trying to do is to pass in one variable which is the ID, then set a veraible out and return a query / cursor.  I got some help on this yesterday, but something is not right and it won't compile.  Can someone help me sort this out? Here is what I have so far.

```
PROCEDURE SEEKER (pMonkeyID IN VARCHAR2, vMarkCounter OUT Number, seeker_cur OUT TYPES.ref_cursor)
AS
BEGIN

CURSOR seeker_cur IS
    Select monkey_doc_approved, monkey_doc_vaulted
    from monkeyApps 
    where MonkeyID = pMonkeyID
    and monkey_doc_type = 'Banana' 
    order by monkey_doc_approved_timestamp,monkey_doc_type,monkey_doc_approved desc

vMarkCounter number:=0;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN seeker_cur 
  LOOP
    vMarkCounter := vMarkCounter+1;
  END LOOP;
END;

END SEEKER;
```

I am not sure I am setting my cursor for returning right, and I am not sure I am looping correctly to set my monkeyMarker. the cursor needs to return as well as the marker because I deal with some front end logic with both.

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: put ; after cursor select statement in declaration section

Comment: good catch that is one problem...It still won't compile.  Choking on the cursor seeker_cur is part...Will this actually return the cursor or do I need to implicitly set the cursor?

Comment: get rid of the first BEGIN.  The first part is the declaration section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll agree with AB Cade I don't understand why you need the records and the count.There should, however, be little to no need to loop though a cursor in PL\SQL; you can use [`bulk collect`](http://psoug.org/reference/array_processing.html) instead, which returns what you want.

If you don't have that many records, say less than 50k I would remove the `limit 10000` part of the bulk collect; you can just use `t_seeker.count`, which'll give you your answer.

```
PROCEDURE SEEKER ( pMonkeyID IN VARCHAR2
                 , vMarkCounter OUT Number
                 , c_seeker OUT TYPES.ref_cursor) IS

  cursor c_seeker is
    select monkey_doc_approved, monkey_doc_vaulted
      from monkeyApps 
     where MonkeyID = pMonkeyID
       and monkey_doc_type = 'Banana' 
     order by monkey_doc_approved_timestamp
            , monkey_doc_type
            , monkey_doc_approved desc
           ;

  type t__seeker is table of c_seeker%rowtype index by binary_integer;
  t_seeker t__seeker;

  vMarkCounter number := 0;

begin

  open c_seeker;
  loop

     fetch c_seeker bulk collect into t_seeker limit 10000;

     vMarkCounter := vMarkCounter + t_seeker.count;

  end loop;

  -- OP want's to return a ref_cursor.
  --close c_seeker;

end seeker;
/
```

Comment: I am not sure if everything is right here.  For example I and trying to pull the ref cursor of seeker_cur.  Where is that being set in the proc, also I have a c_seeker, t_seeker and a t__seeker (I don't understand this).

Comment: I think I have discovered something else or maybe it is my only problem.  I am passing in vMarkCounter, then in the proc I am setting it or manipulating it.  Could this cause oracle to error? I do the vmarkCounter, should I not declare it? If I don't will it bpass the value back to me and I can just pick this up from my front side application? Thoughts?

Comment: @FrankTudor, if you're parsing `vmarkcounter` in then why is it just an **out**? I coded it this way to make it more efficient to do your select and count. I personally wouldn't return a ref_cursor with either my method or yours. In both you've already selected all the data so why would you want to do it again? Mine put's it in a user defined type so you can return an object, which is stored in memory, which already contains all your data... I wouldn't suggest you do anything you're not comfortable with or don't understand though. It'll make it much harder to maintain.

Comment: I understand I completely refactored the procedure.  Thanks for the great code help!

Answer (score 1):

I think that getting both the records and the number of them is wrong. 
But if that's what you want the you can do it like this:

```
PROCEDURE SEEKER (pMonkeyID IN VARCHAR2, vMarkCounter OUT Number, seeker_cur OUT TYPES.ref_cursor)
AS

BEGIN

    OPEN seeker_cur for Select monkey_doc_approved, monkey_doc_vaulted 
                         from monkeyApps where MonkeyID = pMonkeyID  and monkey_doc_type = 'Banana' order by monkey_doc_approved_timestamp,monkey_doc_type,monkey_doc_approved desc;

    Select count(*) INTO vMarkCounter  from (Select monkey_doc_approved, monkey_doc_vaulted 
                         from monkeyApps where MonkeyID = pMonkeyID  and monkey_doc_type = 'Banana');


END SEEKER;
```

But again, check if you really need to count the rows before you even fetched them ...

Comment: Don't use dynamic SQL when static SQL works. Static SQL is safer and faster. Use `OPEN seeker_cur FOR SELECT...` and `SELECT COUNT(*) INTO vMarkCounter...`

Comment: +1 :) although nitpicking, `COUNT` only accepts one argument. Also `OPEN c FOR (SELECT ...)` doesn't compile, you need to remove the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks again, i hope there are no compilation errors now 9I can't chech them). The inner select isn't needed but it's better